# Problema con una Query Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo el siguiente mnodelado de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me piden la siguiente query

> realizar una consulta que devuelva el nombre y apellidos de los atletas que hayan participado en una competición, la descripción de dicha competición, la fecha en que el atleta participó y el estadio donde se llevó a cabo, para aquellas competiciones en que hayan participado atletas que estén federados en la ‘Union Cycliste Internationale’. Se desea adicionalmente que se filtren los resultados para mostrar solo los atletas de género masculino, que hayan ganado la medalla de Oro, y sólo para el/los estadio/s ubicado/s en la ciudad de ‘Salvador’. Adicionalmente, se desean filtrar las pruebas para que se muestren solo aquellas a las que haya asistido el espectador con idDocument '24758693K'. 
>   Mostrad los resultados ordenados por fecha, en orden descendente (primero fecha más reciente)

Tengo ya mucho avanzado solo me falta la parte final donde dice que

> Adicionalmente, se desean filtrar las pruebas para que se muestren solo aquellas a las que haya asistido el espectador con idDocument '24758693K

Esto es lo que tengo y va bien la cosa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cuando pongo esto `AND person.iddocument= '24758693K'` me desaparecen todos los registros y he comprobado mediante otras querys y ver la base de datos que me deberían aparecer 3 registros...Y me pasa esto..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que me falla?Algún tipo de relación?Quizás la select no se hace así?
Ya probé muchas cosas pero no lo consigo.

Pongo el codigo de la query

```
select 
person.firstname,person.lastname,competition.compdescription,venue.venue,
federation.federation,score.dateresult,venue.venue
from person,score,athlete,venue,federation,competition,city,assist
where person.idperson=athlete.idathlete 
and athlete.idathletefed = federation.idfederation
and score.idathlete = athlete.idathlete
and score.idcompetition = competition.idcompetition
and competition.idvenue = venue.idvenue
and venue.idvenuecity=city.idcity
and assist.spectatorid=person.idperson
and person.gender = 'M'
and score.score in ('Gold') 
and federation.federation in ('Union Cycliste Internationale')
and city.cityname in ('Salvador')
group by
person.firstname,
person.lastname,
competition.compdescription,
venue.venue,
federation.federation,
score.dateresult,
venue.venue;
```

Comment: Primero de todo, no pongas imagenes de tu código, copialo aqui para que se te pueda ayudar, y segundo, intenta hacer inner joins entre las tablas en vez de tanto where

Comment: @ValentínSánchezBoto Ok,edito ahora mismo.Respecto al tema de los joins,no se nos permiten usar los joins...Se que son mejor pero no nos lo permiten,por eso tanto where...

Comment: a que se debe que no puedas usarlos?

Comment: @ValentínSánchezBoto En las explicaciones que se nos dieron nos dijeron que usaramos: where nombretabla.idtabla = nombretabla2.idtabla2. Se que esta manera es antigua y demas pero las normas fueron esas...Yo mismo pregunte el porque y se limitaron a decirme porque si....Alguna idea para el "Problema" que tengo?No se en que fallo..

Comment: @ValentínSánchezBoto Codigo añadido.

Comment: A que viene el group by? Por que doble venue.venue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica en la comprensión del enunciado, en concreto:

> Adicionalmente, se desean filtrar las pruebas para que se muestren
>   solo aquellas a las que haya asistido el **espectador** con idDocument
>   '24758693K'.

Como bien te indica, solo desea que se muestren las pruebas en las que ha asistido un espectador. No dice que esa persona sea atleta, y sin embargo en tu query estás forzando a que si lo sea, concretamente con la linea:

> person.idperson=athlete.idathlete

Por otro lado, lo que se te pide es que filtres **las pruebas** a las que ha asistido, no los atletas. Por tanto, la solución que te devuelva no deberá ser un listado para el idDocument que te dan, sino para cada una de las pruebas a las que ese idDocument ha asistido como público, el listado de todos los corredores que han competido en ellas.

Ya que no te permiten hacer joins, una posible solución sería, en lugar de traerse toda la tabla de "Competition", traerte solo las competiciones a las cuales ha asistido el especador con idDocument='24758693K'. Partiendo de tu query, quizás sería algo así:

```
select 
person.firstname,person.lastname,comp.compdescription,venue.venue,
federation.federation,score.dateresult,venue.venue
from person,score,athlete,venue,federation,city,assist, 

(
select competition.*
from competition, person, assist
where assist.spectatorid=person.idperson
and assist.idcompetition=competition.idcompetition
and person.iddocument='24758693K'
) comp

where person.idperson=athlete.idathlete 
and athlete.idathletefed = federation.idfederation
and score.idathlete = athlete.idathlete
and score.idcompetition = comp.idcompetition
and comp.idvenue = venue.idvenue
and venue.idvenuecity=city.idcity
and person.gender = 'M'
and score.score in ('Gold') 
and federation.federation in ('Union Cycliste Internationale')
and city.cityname in ('Salvador')
group by
person.firstname,
person.lastname,
comp.compdescription,
venue.venue,
federation.federation,
score.dateresult,
venue.venue;
```

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: creo que no es asi...Pone claramente en la primera linea "realizar una consulta que devuelva el nombre y apellidos de los atletas que hayan participado en una competición" Por lo tanto la query debe mostrar los atletas pero de las competiciones donde fuera espectador el espectador con iddocument X....Vamos eso esta claro...

Comment: En primer lugar, quizás no estuviese claro el final de mi mensaje, pero efectivamente, era eso lo que pretendía decirte. Ya lo he editado para intentar ser más claro.

En segundo lugar, tu fallo continúa siendo el mismo, y es lo que reproduzco en la primera parte de mi comentario. En tu query estás exigiendo que el idDocument '24758693K' sea atleta, cuando no lo es.

Por último, si pusieras el código en lugar de una captura de pantalla quizás sería más sencillo reproducir tu query.

Comment: Pongo el codigo sin problemas ,todo ayuda es bienvenida.Codigo añadido.

Comment: Editado con una posible solución. El problema de base sigue siendo el que te indicaba al principio, en tu query le estás pidiendo a una persona que sea atleta, espectador y además con idDocument='24758693K'.

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta que es como tu me has expuesto pero me da error la query...Me dice ORA-00904: "COMPETITION"."COMPDESCRIPTION": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error en la línea: 2, columna: 34................Porque puede deberse este error?Lo que veo que haces es "Crear" otra select que te trae solo las competiciones a las que fue el idDocument='24758693K' y lo conviernes en un campo "Comp"...¿Debe ser por eso el error que me lanza?Si quito el COMPETITION"."COMPDESCRIPTION me da los 3 resultados que tienen que darme pero me falta eso

Comment: Hago una subquery de la tabla "Competition" y la trato como una tabla a la cual llamo "comp". Esa tabla ya solo tiene las competiciones a las cuales ha acudido como espectador el  '24758693K', así que el resto de la query debe ser igual a como la tenías. He editado la respuesta, en el Select en lugar de "competition.compdescription" había que poner "comp.compdescription". Espero que ahora ya te funcione.

Comment: me va perfectamente,solo puedo agraderte esto,llevaba dos dias loco con ella.